# Using threads to count the number of perfect Squares in a given array

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I am trying to count the number of perfect squares in a given array using threads.
Each thread is supposed to take a part of the array and search for the number of perfect squares in that exact part. Then the number of squares in that certain part is to be added to the global amount of perfect squares in the entire array.

Below is my SquareCounterImpl class.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;



public class SquareCounterImpl  {
    public static int count = 0;
    public static int div;
    public static long t[];
    public int countSquares(long[] numbers, int nThreads)
    {
        //count = nThreads;
        t = numbers;
        div = numbers.length/nThreads;
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
        for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
            exec.execute(new MeinRunnable(i));
            try
             {exec.wait();}catch(Exception e){}
        }
        return count;

    }

    static boolean isPerfectSquare(long n)
    {
        int i =1;
        while(true)
        {
        if(n < 0)
            return false;
        if(n == 0 )
            return true;
        n-=i;
        i+=2;
        }
    }

    protected static class MeinRunnable extends Thread {
        final int n;

        public MeinRunnable(int i) {
            n = i;
        }
        synchronized void incrementSync() {
            count = count + 1;
        }

        public void run() {
            //System.out.println((div*n )+ "-" + (div*(n+1)) );
                for(int i=div*n ; i < div*(n+1); i++)
                {
                    if(isPerfectSquare(t[i]));
                    incrementSync();
                }


        }
}
}
```

This is my main.

```
public class SquareCounterMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SquareCounterImpl n = new SquareCounterImpl();
        final long[] n2 = new long[] {1l,4l,9l,16l,25l,36l,49l,64l,81l,100l};
        int k = n.countSquares(n2, 2);
        System.out.println(k);

    }

}
```

It seems that my count is always stuck at 5 (the number of perfect squares in the first division of the array). Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here. Thank you .

Comment: Please do not name your classes "___Impl". It offends me.

Comment: What should the correct answer be?

Comment: @SteveSmith The correct answer is supposed to be 10 since I have two threads. Each thread will take a division of 5 elements from the array and since each one of the elements is a perfect square, the first thread is supposed to return 5 and the second thread is supposed to return 5. Therefore the total amount of perfect squares (i.e count) should be 10.

Answer (score 1):

You're not waiting for the threads to finish before you output the `count`.  Instead of `wait()`, you need something like:

```
exec.shutdown();
try {
  exec.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  ...
}
```

Also, I think you have a bug:

```
if(isPerfectSquare(t[i]));
incrementSync();
```

should be

```
if(isPerfectSquare(t[i])) {
    incrementSync();
}
```

I would also use AtomicInteger instead of a static int.

Comment: I fixed the bug, thank you . I am still only getting 5 perfect squares.

Comment: You're still not waiting for the threads to finish.  See my edit.

Comment: after implementing your fix I am now getting a  java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException .

Comment: exec.shutdown() was what was causing the exception from your fix. Thank you very much though.

Comment: The extra code needs adding outside the loop.  Don't forget to mark this answer if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for easier parallelism

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    try (LongStream longs = LongStream.range(1, 3_900_000)) {
        long count = longs.parallel().filter(n -> isPerfectSquare(n)).count();

        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000);

        System.out.println(count);
    }
}

private static boolean isPerfectSquare(long n) {
    int i = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (n < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (n == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        n -= i;
        i += 2;
    }
}
```